# Open links in Notepad++ with keyboard

Tags: notepad++

I can open internet links in Notepad++ by double clicking on a link. Is there a way to do this only using keyboard? I mean are there any key board short cuts to achieve this?

Comment: do you mean href links, and when you open you say they open in browser. Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @refhat: exactly as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, no. At least in Notepad++ 6.1.2

In Settings > Preferences > Misc you have only "Enable **Clickable** Links" - not a word about keyboard.

In Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Main Menu, Run commands or Scintilla Commands there is no reference to this.

A macro cannot be recorded with this in order to assign a shortcut to this macro.

The "Launch in..." commands send the entire file to the chosen browser.

Of course, if you'll find a suitable plugin to do just that then you're lucky. Install it and assign a shortcut to it.

*...but if you're quite extreme you can enable (on Windows) Mouse Keys and use the numeric pad as a mouse, hence you'll have the "left click" on the keyboard.*

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add to notepad++ a shortcut that launches the default browser with the selected text as a link.

Here is how to add the shortcut:

1. Open Notepad++ shortcuts file: `%appdata%\notepad++\shortcuts.xml`
2. At the end of `<UserDefinedCommands>` section, add:
   A shortcut with the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```xml
   <Command name="Open Link" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="yes" Key="13">explorer &quot;$(CURRENT_WORD)&quot;</Command>
   ```

   Or a shortcut with no defined key binding:

   ```xml
   <Command name="Open Link" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">explorer &quot;$(CURRENT_WORD)&quot;</Command>
   ```

   you can define the key binding in Notepad++ itself (Settings > Shortcut Mapper > Run commands).
3. Restart notepad++.

**Note**: When the selected text is a local folder or file path, it will open the folder with file explorer or the file with the default program.

**How it works**: This solution works by calling windows file explorer with the selected text as an argument, so it is actually like opening file explorer and typing the link in the address bar.

This answer is based on the answer I found here: [Launch in default Web browser](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/19192/launch-in-default-web-browser/1?_=1602167605616&lang=en-US), but I think its safer because it cant run any command, it just opens what file explorer knows how to open.

Answer (score 0):

**How it works:**

You select the whole line (e.g. `Shift`+`End`) and then push `Ctrl`+`Enter`
(or select only the link, but that is slower).

If the line contain a `http*` or `www*` string it will be opended in your browser, i.e. the line can contain other pre- or suffixed text, it will be trimed.

**How to implement:**

Add this/these line(s) to `%appdata%Notepad++\shortcuts.xml` in the `<UserDefinedCommands>` element:

```xml
<!-- Shortcut: CTRL+ENTER -->
<Command name="Launch in Edge" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="13">&quot;C:\util\OpenLink.cmd&quot; $(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
<!-- Shortcut: CTRL+K -->
<Command name="Launch in Edge" Ctrl="yes" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="75">&quot;C:\util\OpenLink.cmd&quot; $(CURRENT_WORD)</Command>
```

[image]

The content of the script-files `OpenLink.cmd`, which extract the link from the line and open the browser, is:

```
@echo off
SET BrowserPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" 
:loop
SET Str=%~1
REM echo TextPart: %Str%
IF %Str:~0,4%==http (
   REM echo Execute: %Str%
   cmd /c %BrowserPath% %Str%
)
IF %Str:~0,3%==www (
   REM echo Execute: %Str%
   cmd /c %BrowserPath% %Str%
)
SHIFT
IF NOT "%~1"=="" GOTO loop
REM pause
```

(sorry about Edge....you replace it with something better okay. Also be aware CTRL+K might already be taking, please check in the shortcut gui)

*The command-variable [$(CURRENT_WORD)](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#userdefinedcommands) grab the selected text and parse it to the cmd script. Unfortunately there are no command-variable in NPP to grab the whole line so you don't have to do it yourself first, one could hope for it in the future.
Another improvement could be to make a macro which select the whole-line and then execute either a defined NPP command or execute the cmd  scriptfile, but that doesn't seem to be possible in a macro :-(. So you have to select the whole line/hyperlink string first. I made a feature-request [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/11216)*